Is hardwiring considered as a good practice?
I'm a second-semester CE student, and in our programming courses, they say that it's a bad practice to hardcode things, because compilers are geniuses and can optimize everything!
However, I'm sure that in designing circuits, that's not the case, and optimizations are important because there's no compiler. However, I'm not sure whether we should consider things like extensibility, maintainability, and reusability in our circuit, or not.
For instance, consider the following problem in our homework, whose purpose is making telephone controller circuits using an ASM chart:

This telephone only accepts 10 IRR coins and shows the number of available coins on two 7-segment displays. (Maximum 99 coins)
To make a call, you have to put the desired number (at least one coin) into the phone and then press the start button. As soon as a phone call is made, 10 rials will be deducted from the balance, and the light indicating the call will be turned on, which will remain on until the end of the call. From now on, 10 rials will be deducted from the balance for every T1 second (2 clock pulses). When the balance reaches zero, the warning light will turn on.
During the conversation and even after the warning light is on, it's possible to increase the coins. If a coin is not added T2 seconds (3 clock pulses) after the alarm is turned on, the phone call will go dead. that is, the phone call indicator will turn off, and the alarm will remain on, while with the increase of coins, the phone call will continue, and the alarm will go off.

You can see my ASM chart here, and below:
 
As you can see, I created three different states for the call, hoping it would reduce electrical load while not being sure. This hardwiring seems like a hardcode to me, as we can't change the maximum duration that the speaker can talk without any money in their account, thus the final circuit mayn't be maintainable.
Here you can see the answer of my classmates to this problem they had in this course in the last semester here on GitHub:

Their approach is they put the U5 and U7 gates that detect the balance has reached zero, and they give that signal to the gate U12 which triggers the U9 counter to count three times, and when it counts until three, the call will be interrupted.
So, my question is, which approach do you think is better? Using a counter to count until 3 which is more maintainable, but has the counterbalance of using more gates and power in the circuit, or do hardwire in my approach? (I have to draw the circuit via proteus, but I haven't done it yet)

isn't that for you to decide? ... why do you require the opinion of some random stranger on the internet?

""I'm not sure whether we should consider things like extensibility, maintainability, and reusability in our circuit, or not."" - Yes, Always, and Yes.

Along with a load of other things like cost, size, reliability, component availability, operating temperature, etc. etc. There's never an absolute "best", just best for a particular set of requirements, As most pros would use a microcontroller for this, it's just an academic exercise to make you think about it.

During the era where logic circuits like this were used, configuration would come in the form of dip switches or similar. Besides that, all logic would be "hard wired" as you say. The board would have a specific and well documented function.
